# Calling a particular function when multiple events are bound

Tags: javascript

I have a site wide JS, which creates listeners for various events, but in certain conditions I need to call a particular function, like in code below, I need to call function **call**, but its not getting called.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function ()
{    
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var len = inputs.length;

   for (var i=0; i < len; i++) 
   {        
         if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "text") 
         {    
                  var element = inputs[i];

                  element.onfocus = function() 
                  {    
                        var id = element.getAttribute("id");
                        alert(id);
                  }
          }
   }
}

function call(element)
{    
      element.value="";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="myvar1" value="same content" id="noviceid" onfocus="call(this);">
<input type="text" name="myvar2" value="same content" id="noviceid" onfocus="call(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest. I would like to call both **onfocus**. I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, once your page has loaded (with proper `call` `onfocus` handlers), you run `window.onload` that overwrites all these handlers. I guess it's not what you intended to do. Instead, you can use DOM2 events, if possible:

```
element.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
      {
            var id = event.target.getAttribute("id");
            alert(id);
      }, false);
```

Comment: That works if OP wants to execute both at the same time all the time. OP also stated `but in certain conditions I need to call a particular function` which would imply only sometimes would he/she like to execute the other method. Also it isn't made very clear by OP if in that instance he/she would like to execute both or just one instead of the other.

Comment: Right, I didn't completely grasp the idea, too, but gave a snippet OP could base off of.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your solution is spot on given the little information one has from the question. I meant this comment more for the OP than you :)

Comment: I would like to execute both functions in those is scenarious. Sorry for not mentioning this in question. will edit.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov : Your solution is working in firefox, but in safari I am getting to see infinite alert windows.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl : I've tried to include as many details as possible. Can you please tell as to what more I should have added ?, So that I keep in mind for my future queries. Thanks.

Comment: @NonameNoname: I believe the Safari behavior is correct: when you focus an element, an alert instantly comes up, stealing focus from the focused element. Once the alert is closed, the focus is returned to the previously focused element, calling the onfocus listener once again, infinitely. You should not run `alert()` in this listener.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov : Okay. Many thanks for your answer. I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: @NoviceUser: You are missing nothing anymore, after I mentioned the first time it wasn't clear you changed your post and did clarify :) All clear. Also +1 on accepted answer `@Alexander Pavlov`